# Windows 7 NVIDIA driver update error

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have an Intel graphics card and I'm trying to update to an NVIDIA graphics card. Whenever I run the installer it says "Could not find the compatible graphics hardware" and exits.

How can I troubleshoot this error?

Comment: More information is required to help

Comment: In order to use an NVIDIA driver you must have an NVIDIA graphics card currently installed. Based on the question it's unclear whether you have upgraded the card (ie. removed the Intel card and installed an NVIDIA one) or are simply trying to install the NVIDIA driver without an NVIDIA card installed. The latter will not work because the driver is specific to the hardware and an Intel card is not the same as an NVIDIA one in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've physically installed the NVIDIA card into the AGP slot of your PC (or some other appropriate slot inside the PC). If so, then you may also have to go to the BIOS settings for your machine and cause it to disable the on-board Intel graphics chip in favor of the second video card. Once you return to Windows, your video may be dumbed down to simple VGA resolution until you retry that video driver installation. It ought to work then! In fact, Windows might itself attempt to install the updated NVIDIA driver for you before you get a chance to install from your media.